# What script adjustments do I need to make to convert from V8 Runtime to Rhino Runtime (Legacy)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The V8 Runtime has a problem with creating triggers by script so I need to convert to the old script template, but when trying to convert to Legacy, it doesn't save for two problems:

**Original Script Part 1:**

```
function installFunctions() {
  const excludedFunctions = ["onOpen", "installFunctions"];

  const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Funções do GAS');
  for (let i in this) {
    if (typeof this[i] == "function" && !excludedFunctions.includes(i)) {
      menu.addItem(i, i);
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  installFunctions();
}
```

*Not saved because it contains a `Missing ; after the for-loop launcher.` error in this line of code:*

```
  for (let i in this) {
```

**Original Script Part 2:**

```
function deleteTriggerWithName(name) {
  const trs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t => t.getHandlerFunction());
  const ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(ts[trs.indexOf(name)]);
}
```

*Not saved because it contains a `Syntax Error` in this line of code:*

```
  const trs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t => t.getHandlerFunction());
```

Comment: Remove arrow notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modifications

- Arrow functions are not supported in Rhino, so changed the `map` function into a normal `for` loop that adds items to an array.
- It seems that while `const` is supported, using `let` in a `for` loop initialization is not. So replaced everything with `var` to be safe

#### Script

```js
function installFunctions() {
  var excludedFunctions = ["onOpen", "installFunctions"];

  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Funções do GAS');
  for (var i in this) {
    if (typeof this[i] == "function" && !excludedFunctions.includes(i)) {
      menu.addItem(i, i);
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}



function deleteTriggerWithName(name) {
  var trs = []

  for (var trigger in ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()){
    trs.push(trigger.getHandlerFunction())
  }
  var ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(ts[trs.indexOf(name)]);
}
```

This saved successfully in the script editor.

#### Reference

- [V8 overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)

#### EDIT:

```js
function deleteTriggerWithName(name) {
  var trs = []
  var projectTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
  
  for (var i=0; i != projectTriggers.length; i++) {
    trs.push(projectTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction())
  }

  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(projectTriggers[trs.indexOf(name)]);
}
```

Comment: Hi mate: The error ```TypeError: Cannot find function getHandlerFunction on object 0.``` appears on that line of code ```trs.push(trigger.getHandlerFunction())``` , Could you help me modify it so that the function works? Thanks in advance

Comment: This would probably be best answered by asking another question, that said, I have made an edit, try that version of the function see if it works.