# TypeError: Cannot find includes function in object (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script cannot be used in Google App Script V8 model, because there is a problem that causes triggers that are created automatically via script to crash.

So I need to use Legacy Mode, old version of GAS.

I'm trying to adjust the script so that a Menu is created in the spreadsheet, containing all the functions in the file.

This model works perfectly on V8:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68053222/11462274

```
function installFunctions() {
  const excludedFunctions = ["onOpen", "installFunctions"];

  const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Funções do GAS');
  for (let i in this) {
    if (typeof this[i] == "function" && !excludedFunctions.includes(i)) {
      menu.addItem(i, i);
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  installFunctions();
}
```

However, in Legacy mode it doesn't work, so I was initially asked to make these changes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064124/11462274

```
function installFunctions() {
  var excludedFunctions = ["onOpen", "installFunctions"];

  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Funções do GAS');
  for (var i in this) {
    if (typeof this[i] == "function" && !excludedFunctions.includes(i)) {
      menu.addItem(i, i);
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  installFunctions();
}
```

But, it returns the error mentioned in the question `TypeError: Cannot find includes function in object onOpen,installFunctions.`, so I saw an indication to change the `includes` for `indexOf`, the Menu is created, but only with the `OnOpen function` appear, which in this case actually shouldn't appear because it should be excluded.

[image]

Full Script Test:

```
function installFunctions() {
  var excludedFunctions = ["onOpen", "installFunctions"];

  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Funções do GAS');
  for (var i in this) {
    if (typeof this[i] == "function" && !excludedFunctions.includes(i)) {
      menu.addItem(i, i);
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  installFunctions();
}

function ClimaParaTestes() {
}

function JogosParaClimaParaTestes() {
}

function EnviarClimasParaSquads() {
}

function ApagarHistoricoDoClima() {
}

function deleteTriggerWithName(name) {
}
```

What do I need to modify in the script to make it work in Legacy mode?

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with yours. it actually works on mine. Added a function named `otherFunction` and that's the only one that popped into the menu using Legacy mode. `includes` definitely works and no errors similar to yours. I did encounter an issue before making it work and it's not related to includes (just an error resulting to empty menu). Just added another function and it worked.

Comment: Hi @NaziA I added the error alert to the question, Below these lines of script that I published, there are 5 functions, but unfortunately the Menu is not even created.

Comment: Are there special characters in your function names? can you at least provide or show them? just remove the contents of these functions in your post.

Comment: I add in my question the name of functions @NaziA

Comment: can you try `var excludedFunctions = new Array("onOpen", "installFunctions");` instead? It seems the issue in your case is that it reads your excluded functions as object. I wonder if it works using `Array()` function. Reference, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: . @NaziA Thank you in advance for taking the time to try and help me. About the change tip, unfortunately the same error persists. I can share the entire script if you want, there's nothing important in them, if you think it might be useful I do.

Comment: Feel free. But I'm not sure if the contents of the functions matter. but if it isn't a hassle. please do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234042/discussion-between-nazia-and-brondby-if).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After confirming in tests that it really doesn't work on your side. You can use `indexOf` instead.

#### Use:

```
if (typeof this[i] == "function" && excludedFunctions.indexOf(i) < 0) {
```

#### Instead of:

```
if (typeof this[i] == "function" && !excludedFunctions.includes(i)) {
```